# Byte[] as parameter in Json

Tags: c#, json

Here is my json:

```
byte[] attachmentBytes = ZipToBase64();
string json = "{ \"method\": \"Bug.add_attachment\", " +
              "  \"params\": [ {" +
                       "  \"ids\": " + "             \"" + "25" +"\", " +
                       "  \"data\": " + "             \"" + attachmentBytes + "\", " +
                       "  \"file_name\": " + "   \"BugReport.zip\", " +
                       "  \"Bugzilla_login\": " + "  \"mymail@hotmail.com\", " +
                       "  \"Bugzilla_password\": " + "             \"mypassword\", " +
                       "  \"summary\": " + "             \"blah blah\", " +
                       "  \"content_type\": " + "   \"application/octet-stream\" " +
                              "  } ], " +
                            "\"id\": 1"
               + "}";

public static byte[] ZipToBase64()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\John\Desktop\SomeArchive.zip";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
            string encoded = encodedData;
            return filebytes;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I think the problem is in the attachmentBytes part, since it is a byte[]. How to pass byte[] in json?

The code is in C#.

Comment: You can convert each byte to base64string and then convert it back on the receiving side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're trying to concatenate a byte[] to a string. That won't work. I'm guessing the error you're getting is a compile error about this concatenation, right?

Instead of returning the byte[], return the base64 string that `Convert.ToBase64String` returns. You can embed that string in your JSON.

While we're on the subject, you can drastically shorten your file reading by simply calling `File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)`, which encapsulates all the filestream business so you won't have to.

Comment: But now I get error "Can't parse JSON data". The method Bug.add_attachment has for an input byte[] for data.

Comment: With my code, I don't get error, but the zip file I'm trying to upload is damaged.

Comment: First of all - is there a reason you're not using a JSON library such as JSON.NET, which will save you this extra work of serializing your objects yourself?
Secondly - who throws this exception? Your code? The service you're sending the JSON to? Where does all this happen? Show us the code where the exception occurs, and some context.

Comment: @AvnerShahr-Kashtan With my code there isn't an exception, the json response is ok and the file is uploaded, but it is damaged. With your code, in the json response I get error Can't process json data.
And yes, I must serialize by hand :(

Comment: Then maybe the service you're uploading the attachment to doesn't support base64 encoding, or expects them serialized in a specific format. 
Try saving the whole json string to a file - or copy-pasting it - and dump it into a JSON validator, like http://jsonlint.com/. This will tell you if your JSON is malformed.

Comment: Well since the response I get from the server is fine, the json can't be malformed, right?

Comment: I found the error: the parameter I send has this format: [80][75][3]...[45], but it should have this format: UEsDBC0AAAAIAONzTkAiH3jE//////////8XABQAV2luZG93c0Fwc...rL+i63At
Can you pls tell me what kind is the second format?

Comment: The second format seems to be a Base64 string. Your first format seems to be some other form of serialized byte[], where each byte is rendered as its numeric value rather than as a character. Is this what you get from the `Convert.ToBase64String` method?

Comment: @AvnerShahr-Kashtan I get [80][75][3]...[45] from my ZipToBase64() method. How to convert it to the Base64 string?

Comment: See the original answers Shai and I gave you. Your ZipToBase64 method doesn't actually do anything: it converts to base64, but then returns the ORIGINAL bytes read from the file. Change the signature to return `string` and return the results of the `Convert.ToBase64String`

Answer (score 0):

Change `ZipToBase64` so it will return a `String` rather than a `byte array`.

```
public static string ZipToBase64()
{
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\John\Desktop\SomeArchive.zip";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes, 
                                      Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
    }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: But now I get error "Can't parse JSON data". The method Bug.add_attachment has for an input byte[] for data.

Comment: With my code, I don't get error, but the zip file I'm trying to upload is damaged.